# find values using collection and not model in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to query MongoDB through mongoose without having a model defined.

This query in NoSQLBooster will generate the correct result.

```
db.coins.find({ "serverTime" : { $gt :  "1523441870", $lt : "1523441999"}});
```

--

The below find() will return with info from the database. But it will not return the expected documents from the database. It will not return any results.

```
const db = myDB = mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI, (err, db) => {
  myDB = db;
});

db
.then(db => {
  connection = mongoose.connection;
    console.log('Mongodb has been connected', myDB);
    //connection.collection("coins").find({ "serverTime" : { $gt :  "1523441870", $lt : "1523441999"}}, function (err, info) {
      connection.collection("coins").find({}, function (err, info) {
      console.log("info: ", err);
      console.log("info: ", info);
    });
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Error while trying to connect with mongodb');
    throw err;
});
```

---

```
Cursor {pool: null, server: null, disconnectHandler: Store, bson: BSON, ns: "dev.coins", …}
index.js:29
_events:Object {}
_eventsCount:0
_maxListeners:undefined
_readableState:ReadableState {objectMode: true, highWaterMark: 16, buffer: BufferList, …}
bson:BSON {}
cmd:Object {find: "dev.coins", limit: 0, skip: 0, …}
cursorState:Object {cursorId: null, cmd: Object, documents: Array(0), …}
destroyed:false
disconnectHandler:Store {s: Object, length: <accessor>}
domain:null
logger:Logger {className: "Cursor"}
namespace:Object
ns:"dev.coins"
options:Object {readPreference: ReadPreference, skip: 0, limit: 0, …}
pool:null
readable:true
readPreference:ReadPreference
s:Object {numberOfRetries: 5, tailableRetryInterval: 500, currentNumberOfRetries: 5, …}
server:null
sortValue:undefined
topology:Server {domain: null, _events: Object, _eventsCount: 23, …}
__proto__:Readable {setCursorBatchSize: , cursorBatchSize: , setCursorLimit: , …}
```

Comment: The `info` is a [Cursor](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html) object. You need to call `toArray(callback)` on it to get all results as an array.

Comment: excellent! But how do I continue drilling down? Promise { pending }
index.js:32
[[PromiseStatus]]:"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]:Array(3)
length:3
__proto__:Array(0) [, …]
0:Object {_id: ObjectID, serverTime: "1523441876", BTC: Object, …}
1:Object {_id: ObjectID, serverTime: "1523441882", BTC: Object, …}
2:Object {_id: ObjectID, serverTime: "1523441888", BTC: Object, …}

Comment: `toArray()` returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Learn more about  [async logic](https://javascript.info/async) and re-visit the [mongodb driver docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/) it will be much more clearer.

Answer (score 4):

When you call methods on mongoose.connection.collection, you are actually accessing the native driver that mongoose relies on provided by mongodb. [The documentation for that driver exists here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/).

[.find()](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#find) in this context returns a [cursor](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#toArray) that has a [toArray method](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#toArray) which either accepts a callback or returns a promise.

You can just move your callback from the `.find()` call to the `.toArray()` call like this:

```
  connection.collection("coins").find({}).toArray(function (err, info) {
    console.log("info: ", err);
    console.log("info: ", info);
  })
```

Or you can implement a promise based solution like this:

```
  let results = connection.collection("coins").find({}).toArray()
  results.then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```

Keep in mind, that the resulting array will contain your entire collection. As your collection grows over time, depending on the number of documents and their size, this can cause node.js to run out of heap space and crash.

Comment: it should be `mongoose.connection.db.collection...` to the end

Answer (score 2):

First get the collection.
Take care of the toArray.then promise which holds the information you are looking for.
loop or do what you want with the returned information.

```
const db = myDB = mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI, (err, db) => {
  myDB = db;
});

db
.then(db => {
  connection = mongoose.connection;

  let collection = mongoose.connection.db.collection('coins');
    console.log('Mongodb has been connected', myDB);
//Find the information
    collection.find({ "serverTime" : { $gt :  "1523441870", $lt : "1523441999"}}, function (err, info) {
      //collection.find({}, function (err, info) {

      console.log("info: ", err);
      console.log("info: ", info);
      //Convert to Array.
//The toArray will return a promise with the info you are looking for.
      let array = info.toArray().then(info => {
        console.log("more info: ", info[0]["serverTime"]);
      });
      console.log("info: ", array);
    });
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Error while trying to connect with mongodb');
    throw err;
});
```